# AJAX POST an XML file with Jquery Without Refreshing Browser?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a file test.xml that I want to POST up to a URL that accepts POST parameters,  Is there a way to use Iframes or some other way in order to get around so that I can post the file to a url via the $.ajax function and associating the user file upload form element to a variable? Note I want the contents of that file to be uploaded and not just a file name.

I want to have something like:

```
<input type="file" id="thefile"></input>
```

and in jquery do:

`var something = $(#thefile).contentsofthefiletopost;`

I would like to do this without page refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ is what you need. Just read the docs and it will make sense

Comment: This doesn't tell him how to upload a file via AJAX :/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the jQuery form plugin, which supports file input types:

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

You will have to upload via file input, and then use server-side scripting to read the file, in PHP:

`<? $xml = file_get_contents($_FILES[0]); print $xml; ?>`